# Do you have to use a body scanner in TSA Pre Check lines?

Tags: x-ray-machines, tsa-precheck

Do any of you TSA Pre-Check approved people know if Pre Check allows you to skip the full body scanner in some or most airports?

Comment: This happened to me at Sarasota airport en route to Charlotte. I had the TSA Pre-check on my boarding pass, went through the metal detector -- did NOT beep, then I was basically pushed into the body scanner. No warning at all. After the scan,they held me there to wait for a female to continue the process. They found I was wearing a watch on my left wrist, under my sleeve. And this was after I had SSSS on my previous boarding pass. I am a senior female.

Comment: You haven't really explained if you tried to decline - they might have just assumed you were ok with it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You do not have to use the body scanner for TSA Pre-Check. Most of the time they don't even have the body scanner in that line.

And when I go to an airport that doesn't have a separate TSA pre-check line, like LGA in NY, they give you a card that says TSA pre-check and they send you through the metal detector. Even if you don't have pre-check you can opt not to go through the scanner, but then they pat you down.

If you don't have it and are thinking about getting it I highly recommend it. Don't have to take your shoes off or anything. So much easier. Like the old days of traveling.

As a side note, when you think about it, you can't go through the body scanner if you have pre-check, because you have your shoes on and possibly things in your pockets so the body scan will always fail.

Comment: This is changing - at some airports there is a body scanner in the PreCheck lane, and if you randomly beep when passing through the metal detector, you will be asked to go through the scanner or have the pat down. I do not like this one bit.

Two places I have seen it are JFK Terminal 8 and PDX.

Comment: @MichaelMathews however, you can still opt not to go through the body scanner.

Comment: Right, but then you have to get the patdown. The problem is I now have things in my pockets, my belt and my shoes, and my luggage is already stacked up at the end of the belt. I refuse to leave my wallet sitting in a tub where anyone can take it.